# How to wire up UICollectionView in a custom UIView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm dealing with a strange issue where I cannot wire up UICollectionView when I want to set it up in a custom UIView.

The reason for having it in UIView instead of UIViewController is that I am creating several custom Views and I'm showing only one per time.

Now, the issue I have is that I am able to drag UICollectionView inside my custom UIView nib but I cannot drop any UICollectionViewCell on it.
However, when I do the same thing inside a UIView of a UIVIewController, not only that I am able to drop a cell on it - the cell appears by default.

This is what appears when i place collection view inside a view controller:
[image]

This is when I add it to a custom UIView
[image]

SO my question is, how to add a cell inside a view?

Comment: I think you could only add more on it if there's already a default one. I don't know the exact reason for this, but somehow it might be impossible in this case, as Apple states: Collection views *must* always have at least one cell and may have multiple cells ... And storyboard/XCode disabled it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in view's xib file. Create a separate xib file for your cell and register it in collection view:

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "YourCellNibFileName", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier")
```